# Creating a RegExp expression that limits the maximum input number to 2*pi radians (360 degrees) (in a Flutter app)

Tags: regex, flutter, textfield

I am building a Flutter app that has a textfield input, in which the user types an angle. There is a toggle that allows the user to change the unit between degrees and radians. The angle is related to compass directions, so I naturally want to allow a maximum input values of `360 degrees`, or `2*pi radians`. I have managed to build an expression that works for degrees, which looks like this:

```
r'^\b([0-2]?[0-9]{1,2}|3[0-5][0-9]|360)\b'
```

This expression allows whole numbers between `0 degrees` and `360 degrees`. If there's a way to modify this to allow decimals as well, that would be fantastic, although it isn't absolutely necessary.

Creating an expression that works when a user has toggled the input units to be radians is where I am struggling. Essentially, it needs to allow users to type in a number with up to two decimal places (or none at all) with a maximum of `6.28 radians`. Below you can see what I have managed to put together so far:

```
r'^\b(6|([1-6])\.?|0\.[1-9]\d*)$\b'
```

As you will probably see straight away, this just doesn't work. I am aiming to allow users to input a value between `0 radians` and `6.28 radians`. I also want them to be able to type in a decimal number with no digit in front, such as `.3 radians` and to be able to type in a number with a decimal point but nothing after, such as `3. radians`.

Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong with this? What should my RegExp expression look like, to cater for this? Thank you!

Comment: Converting to double and checking the bounds is way simpler and more clear. Despite regex validators.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With Flutter, I have a `FilteringTextInputFormatter` that looks like so: `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\b(6|([1-6])\.?|0\.[1-9]\d*)$\b')),`. How would I edit this to convert to a double and check the bounds, since the formatter only allows patterns?

Comment: A custom [TextInputFormatter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html) with [formatEditUpdate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter/formatEditUpdate.html). I think it is less time consuming than guaranteeing having a correct regex

Comment: Thanks for that. I will try and build a custom one and I'll let you know how I get on.